# Have to restart dhclient on enterprise network each time lease expires

Tags: networking, networkmanager, dhcp, dhclient

I connect to a WPA2 enterprise network on Debian Jessie using Network Manager on dhclient. It works fine until the lease expires:

```
Feb 04 15:52:31 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549313551.2132] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'user-requested') [100 110 39]
Feb 04 15:52:31 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549313551.2136] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTING
Feb 04 15:52:31 arjun-thinkpad dbus[1346]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Feb 04 15:52:31 arjun-thinkpad systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
Feb 04 15:52:31 arjun-thinkpad dbus[1346]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-10-04 08:23:25 EDT, end at Mon 2019-02-04 16:21:47 EST. --
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPACK of 10.5.15.31 from 172.31.6.194
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 10.5.15.31
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad dbus[1346]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 18 (255.255.192.0)
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 10.5.0.50
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   server identifier 172.31.6.194
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 3600
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   hostname 'arjun-thinkpad'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '172.29.35.194'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8292] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '172.29.40.66'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8293] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '172.25.192.69'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8293] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '128.151.224.6'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8293] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   domain name 'wireless.rochester.edu'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad dbus[1346]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8293] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   wins '172.25.4.143'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8293] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   wins '172.25.4.144'
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: bound to 10.5.15.31 -- renewal in 1378 seconds.
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad NetworkManager[26926]: <info>  [1549311850.8293] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> bound
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad nm-dispatcher[4541]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0]: new request (3 scripts)
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad nm-dispatcher[4541]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Feb 04 15:24:10 arjun-thinkpad systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 04 15:37:53 arjun-thinkpad i3lock[3303]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Feb 04 15:40:54 arjun-thinkpad wpa_supplicant[2828]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 58:97:bd:bc:61:2e [GTK=CCMP]
Feb 04 15:46:10 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5672]:    arjun : TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/arjun ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/iw dev wlp3s0 station dump --debug
Feb 04 15:46:10 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5672]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 04 15:46:10 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5672]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 04 15:46:23 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: USB disconnect, device number 22
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: new high-speed USB device number 23 using xhci_hcd
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=1011, bcdDevice= 0.01
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: Product: Lenovo ThinkPad Dock
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: Manufacturer: Lenovo
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.4: SerialNumber: Rev1.2
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: hub 1-3.4:1.0: USB hub found
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: hub 1-3.4:1.0: 3 ports detected
Feb 04 15:46:24 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'brscan-skey-0.2' sets config #1
Feb 04 15:46:25 arjun-thinkpad kernel: usb 1-3.3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'brscan-skey-0.2' sets config #1
Feb 04 15:47:09 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:47:12 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:47:12 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5774]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Feb 04 15:47:12 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5774]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [arjun]
Feb 04 15:47:17 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:47:22 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5775]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Feb 04 15:47:22 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5775]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [arjun]
Feb 04 15:47:23 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:47:32 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5777]:    arjun : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/mnt/Dropbox/dropbox1-home/Dropbox/Shared/Ergodic_Random_Walk ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/visudo
Feb 04 15:47:32 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5777]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by arjun(uid=0)
Feb 04 15:47:44 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:47:51 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5777]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 04 15:47:51 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:47:57 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5843]:    arjun : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/mnt/Dropbox/dropbox1-home/Dropbox/Shared/Ergodic_Random_Walk ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xl --since 1 hour ago
Feb 04 15:47:57 arjun-thinkpad sudo[5843]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by arjun(uid=0)
Feb 04 15:48:04 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:48:13 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
Feb 04 15:48:25 arjun-thinkpad dhclient[4153]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.5.15.31 on wlp3s0 to 172.31.6.194 port 67
```

Then the DHCP requests fail, until I disconnect from the network and reconnect. I am on kernel 4.18, and I have the latest iwlwifi drivers for an Intel 7265D chipset.

Comment: Looking at the same issue right now; the renewed lease seems blissfully unaware of  wpa_supplicant's presence. Actually stopping & restarting the `dhclient` brings the network back to life ... annoying.